# How to add css class to a div with typescript in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

When I scroll down, the class is not added on the div element.

```
 export class TestComponent {
  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {}

    @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
    checkScroll() {
      var line = this.el.nativeElement;

      for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        var elementTop = line[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var elementVisible = 150;
        if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
          line[i].classList.add('active-line');
        } else {
          line[i].classList.remove('active-line');
        }
      }
      console.log('scrolling');
      console.log(line);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="mx-4 bd-highlight line"></div>
```

I want that when I scroll down to make this div from this `<div class="mx-4 bd-highlight line"></div>` to this `<div class="mx-4 bd-highlight line active-line"></div>`

Comment: Coudl you provide a working example? It will be very find out what the issue is just from the code. I would suspect that your if statement may be fault here and the code for adding a class is just not executed.

Comment: yeah, but I want to be more clear just in case nothing else

Comment: if the if statement may be fault why does it work on javascript? and how to execute that code?

Comment: just tell me one thing how many such divs are there, are you using *ngFor ??

Comment: No, you are asking because of the fro loop right but for scroll there is one div tho otherwise there are a lot of divs

Comment: If you call `line[i].classList.add('active-line');` unconditionally (w/o the `if`), does it add this class to the element?

Comment: I didn't try anyway I fixed the bug so thanks for all of you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.